# ReactJs -TimeTravel - FB tutorial - how does setState in jumpTo work?

Tags: reactjs

The following code is in time-travel section of reactjs tutorial from FB [here](https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html#adding-time-travel):

```
 jumpTo(step) {
    this.setState({
      stepNumber: step,
      xIsNext: (step % 2) === 0,
    });
  }
```

How does `this.setState` exactly work in this code? IMO, it creates immutable copy of current state of `Game` and merges `stepNumber` and `xIsNext` properties into it. How does this exactly achieve time travel?  Shouldn't `jumpTo` delete history after the step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a trickiest part of the tutorial. It is correct that `jumpTo` resets `stepNumber` of the latest status of `Game` component. However `render` method of `Game` component uses `stepNumber` as index to retrieve current `squares` from history. This is very clever indeed. Code excerpt below:

```
render() {
    const history = this.state.history;
    const current = history[this.state.stepNumber];
    const winner = calculateWinner(current.squares);
```

So the answer to question "Shouldn't `jumpTo` chop-off the history until that step?" is No. Also if `jumpTo` tries to modify history then time travel will not be possible, technically speaking.

It's also worth noting that as soon as a historical step is modified by clicking on board, all "future" history from that step becomes invalid. Therefore chopping history is done in `handleClick` method. Code excerpt from `Game` component's `handleClick` method:

```
handleClick(i) {
   const history = this.state.history.slice(0, this.state.stepNumber + 1);
   const current = history[history.length - 1];
   const squares = current.squares.slice();
```